# How to combine two result sets from one table sorted independently using one SQL query?

Tags: java, sql, union, hsqldb

This is a simplified task which I have to solve in real project. In this project data is stored in HSQLDB. Data is accessed using JDBC.

I have one table:

```
name | flag
-----------
aa   | 1
bb   | 0
cc   | 1
dd   | 0
ee   | 1
ff   | 0
```

I need to compose query to get the following table:

```
name | flag
-----------
aa   | 1
cc   | 1
ee   | 1
ff   | 0
dd   | 0
bb   | 0
```

The final table is like rows with flag = 1 were taken and sorted **ascending**, rows with flag = 0 were taken and sorted **descending** and results were combined one after another.

Please, pay attention, that rows with flag = 1 and rows with flag = 0 have **opposite** sort order.

Is it possible to do in SQL? I wouldn`t like to make two queries and merge ResultSets in Java code manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In any SQL, only the outermost order by applies so it has to be done there.

I don't know if this works in your SQL dialect (and can't check sorry), but you could do this

```
SELECT name, flag
FROM  'table'
ORDER BY
    flag desc,
    CASE WHEN flag = 1 THEN name ELSE '' END,
    CASE WHEN flag = 0 THEN name ELSE '' END DESC
```

Comment: Thanks, your solution works in HSQLDB.
But could you please explain how does sorting work in database? Engine selects rows and then applies two kinds of order expressions either this: "flag desc, name, '' desc" (if flag = 1) or this: "flag desc, '', name desc" (if flag = 0)? I have never met dynamic "order by" expression before.

Comment: It sorts on 3 columns, but either column 2 or column 3 is a constant so is effectively ignored

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT name, flag
FROM 'table'
ORDER BY flag desc, name
```

Let the database do the work whenever you can.  Don't do such things in Java.  Think "SQL first".

Comment: Please, pay attention, that column name in rows where flag = 0 has opposite sort order.

Comment: Please write a coherent question and stop being rude.  I'm down voting your question now.

Comment: @Ilya: you added this requirement after this answer

Comment: @gbn - not exactly, the requirement was there before, he just edited it to make it clearer when he saw that people were misunderstanding

Comment: That condition was from the very beginning. After I saw that people were misunderstanding, I made key words bold and added phrase "Please, pay attention..." to make question clearer.
@froadie: Thanks. Everything was exactly as you described.

Answer (score 1):

`order by` can take more than one column:

```
select *
from table
order by flag desc, name asc
```